# File field and using a specific display format with file_view_file

Tags: theming, views, entities

I am using a HOOK, hook_preprocess_node, to create some additional output variables for templates.  One field is a type of FILE which is using the Media module to link a image file to the object.  Using MANAGE DISPLAY, I can set the output to "Rendered File", but when I do this in code, the output looks to be in its default format.

Below is a sample of the code.

```
  function hmtest_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
    if ($variables['type'] == 'presentation') {
       $node = $variables['node'];
       $Afield = field_view_field('node', $node,           
          'field_presentation_backgrounds');
       $variables['backgrounds'] = render($Afield);
    }
  }
```

I know that field_view_field takes a fourth parameter $display, but I'm not quite sure what this would look like.

How do I specify the correct format filter for this field in code when it is setup through the Drupal admin UI?